# Using wmi to trigger query OIDs in NDIS driver

Tags: wmi, ndis, oid

I would like to make wmi query in cs to trigger NDIS OIDs.

For example, to check hardware status (OID_GEN_HARDWARE_STATUS) I can use `ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\WMI", "SELECT * FROM MSNDIS_HardwareStatus")`

I need to make some other requests, but I cannot find any way to find wmi class name for given OID (let's say it's OID_802_3_RCV_OVERRUN, there is no any obvious relation like OID_GEN_HARDWARE_STATUS -> MSNDIS_HardwareStatus for it, at least I have not found one).

How do I find relations between wmi class name and NDIS OIDs? Is there any documentation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific example you cite, `OID_802_3_RCV_OVERRUN`, does not have a corresponding WMI class.  Here's one way to prove that, if you're comfortable using a kernel debugger.

1. Run the kernel debugger command `!ndiskd.miniport -wmi <someHandle>`
2. Search the text output for "OID_802_3_RCV_OVERRUN"
3. There's no matches, so the miniport does not expose that OID to WMI

If you'd rather not use a kernel debugger, or if you just want to see a few more examples, [here's an article I wrote on how to inspect the relationship between WMI classes and OIDs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ndis/2015/03/21/mapping-from-ndis-oids-to-wmi-classes/).